# ToolbarItems visualization problems

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

Hi,

as you can see in the attached picture I am not able to visualize the ToolbarItems both on IPhone and on Android emulators.

Any idea about the reason?

Xamarin Studio Community 6.0.1

Android version 6.0.

iPhone version 9.3.

Thanks

Valerio

[Xamarin.forms ToolbarItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi7mb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationPage` to get access to your toolbar items:

*File App.xaml.cs*

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ToolbarDemoPage());
}
```